# Keycloak unable to connect to SQL Server running on Windows

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, ssl, keycloak

Keycloak container is unable to establish connection to a remote SQL Server database and is stuck in a boot loop.

**Output from container logs:**

```
{"logs":"Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: \"Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints\". ClientConnectionId:8c3fca80-a572-4014-abe0-6e55adf39c44

{"logs":"Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints

{"logs":"Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints

{"logs":"Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Algorithm constraints check failed on keysize limits. RSA 1024bit key used with certificate:
 CN=SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback.  Usage was tls server

{"logs":"\u001B[0m\u001B[31m12:14:07,280 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
```

I’m running Keycloak version 10.0.1 in a docker container on a Linux machine and the SQL Server 2012 DB is hosted on a Windows machine. I've enabled TCP/IP protocol on the SQL Server and configured it to listen on all addresses.

Works absolutely fine when I point the container to SQL Server running on another Linux machine.

Comment: `Windows machine` which version of Windows? Have you tried a 2048 bit RSA key on the certificate, that is standard and more secure anyway

Comment: Its running on Windows Server 2012 R2.
You mean assign the certificate on SQL Server?

Comment: The SSL certificate [that SQL Server is using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: SQL Server 2014 and earlier generate 1024 bit private keys with their [`create certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-certificate-transact-sql) commands. You'll either need to relax the keycloak constraint or find a way to replace the target server's self-signed certificate with another one that has a 2048 bit private key.